# How to find the fringe width of an interference pattern created by a spherical and a plane wave?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, interference

If we have two equations of a spherical and a plane wave (given that the plane wave is propagating along the $z$ direction), how do we find the fringe width of the interference pattern that would be produced on the $x-y$ plane?

I think the interference pattern would be spherical, but any help on finding the fringe width is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Raha, welcome to Physics SE. Please show your own effort in solving the problem. We do not solve homework exercises here.

Comment: What above said and have a look at Fourier optics